# Mongoose doesn't validate nested array in NestJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a nested user schema which has these fields:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { User } from 'src/users/schemas/user.schema';

@Schema({ _id: false })
export class NestedUser {
  @Prop({ required: true, type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
  userId: User;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  email: string;

  @Prop({ required: false, default: '' })
  imageUrl: string;
}

export const NestedUserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(NestedUser);
```

And a role schema which contains an array of NestedUser like this:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { NestedUser, NestedUserSchema } from './nested-user.schema';
import { NestedTemplate, NestedTemplateSchema } from './nested-template.schema';

export type RoleDocument = mongoose.HydratedDocument<Role>;

@Schema()
export class Role {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, type: [NestedTemplateSchema], default: [] })
  templates: NestedTemplate[];

  @Prop({
    required: true,
    type: [NestedUserSchema],
    default: [],
  })
  users: NestedUser[];
}

export const RoleSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Role);
```

When I insert a nested user which looks like this, the sub document is inserted without any validation and accept empty fields:

```
{
   userId: '',
   name: '',
   imageUrl: '',
   email: '',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use class validator for any kind of validation**

```
 @IsArray()
 @ValidateNested({ each: true })
 users: NestedUser[];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Prop({
type: [{ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
validate: [
  (contacts) => contacts.length <= 100,
  'Limit Exceeded',
],
})
```

I also had similar use case which worked for me
its array of objectIDs in my case

Here if contacts <= 100 it will execute or else it will throw error